# Mongodb combine collections in java, and retrieve specific documents

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, join, mongodb-query

I'm trying to combine two collections in MongoDB in Java. The structure of my collections looks like this:

global +- 100k rows:

```
    _id     |     registration     |    type
   _________|______________________|____________
   018024   |        5A-IAY        |    A306
```

type +- 1000 rows:

```
    _id     |     wake    |            code               |   manufacturer   |
   _________|_____________|_______________________________|__________________|
    A306    |      H      |  A300B4-600 /C4-600 / F4-600  |      Airbus      |
```

I want this to be inserted dynamically, so that I can update it. I'm using an arrange of webcrawlers to retrieve this data, and so I want my program to be able to update it and retrieve it.

I've been looking into mongodb refs and embedded documents and my structure while embedded would look like this:

```
_id: 018024
 registration: 5A-IAY
 type: A306
 {
      _id: A306
      wake: H
      type: A-300B4-600/..
      manufacturer: Airbus
 }
```

**My question is:**

*How will I be able to retrieve specific data like this in MongoDB from multiple collections, and how will I be able to update it dynamically?*

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: Why don't you use one collection instead of two?

Comment: How do I combine two collections into one like that?

Comment: What about that embedded document? Or does that give too much duplication?

Comment: I don't know how to embed all these specific documents into specific 100k rows dynamically..